# Issue after running sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am facing some issue while updating openGL.
I had followed the commands 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/501560/how-to-update-opengl-driver-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts
from this link.(particularly answer 2)
Now the issue is after restarting i am getting distorted display. Also i am unable to type anything on terminal. So I cant even purge the changes.

Comment: Firstly it is question that belongs more on askubuntu.com than here. Secondly can you please post the exact commands you used in the body of the question?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have solved the issue.